# Kubuntu 20.10 don't recognizes fedora 33 instalation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

My default distribution is Kubuntu 20.10. In the last few days I installed Fedora 33, which naturally overwrote the grub installed by Kubuntu, which was fixed by a grub-install after logging into Kubuntu via the menu produced by Fedora.
When running grub-customizer, in order to obtain a menu entry for Fedora, that OS was not recognized, even though running os-prober from the command line.
So, I manually created a menu entry, using the existing entries as a template. But the Fedora boot fails with the message "Failed to start Switch root", stopping at the recovery prompt.
I believe that this is due to the fact that the root partition contains a / root folder, where the other system folders are mounted.
I did not find a grub.cfg file in the system that could help me.
searching the Fedora forums I found no answer to this question.
I thank you for some solution.

Comment: is this still of  interest to you?